# Handle .canGoBack() from multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, handle

I have an activity with several fragments containing web views.
I have exposed the web views `canGoBack` and `goBack` to the `MainActivity` of the application.

At the moment I have it working for one fragment, but I am not sure how to check which fragment is sending the information, and in turn how to send the appropriate fragment the response.

Here is the code involved from the MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    circleFragment.canGoBack();
    if (circleFragment.canGoBack()) {
        circleFragment.goBack();

    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of implementing a boolean `canGoBack()`

Just create an interface "Backable"

```
public interface Backable {
    public void goBack();
    public boolean canGoBack();
}
```

Make your `Fragment implement Backable`
and use `if(myFragment instanceof Backable)` to now if your current Fragment is `backable`

So:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(myFragment instanceof Backable) {
        ((Backable) myFragment).canGoBack();
        if(((Backable) myFragment).canGoBack()){
            ((Backable) myFragment).goBack();

        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, where would I put the interface?

Comment: You can define it in a new file called "Backable.java" (same as you would to for a new java class), or inside your Activity.
(FYI: made some mistakes in my code, edited it)

Comment: Ahh yep, just had to remove the () after Backable in order for studio to not complain! So if I want to implement this for n more fragments, how would I do this?

Comment: For each fragment you want compatible, add `implements Backable`

Android Studio will know the fragment handle canGoBack and goBack as long as you casted it into "Backable"

ex:
`public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements Backable`

Comment: Done, however in order to allow onBackPressed to work, I need to give it the name of a fragment. I can understand how onBackPressed now handles a fragment, but not how it can tell the difference between fragments when it is being given a single fragment name. (This is probably something extremely obvious that I'm not picking up!)

Comment: Make a attribute in your Activity like `Fragment curentFragment`. This fragment should change when you change de the fragment.

Use this variable in your `onBackPressed()` method. This way, if the currentFragment is `Backable`, wanted method will be triggered.

Comment: Ahh Yes, so I need to use fragment manager. I should be able to crack on with that!